# save page in php

Tags: php, scope

I am writing a web program using mvc php framework. I have index and another view which I want to render the view inside of my index. First I call view then I call index and put view into it. My problem is I want to save the whole view into a variable and do something like echo $view in my index. both require_once and include_once will show my view instantly. I want to save the page with it's variables. Any idea?

Comment: which mvc framework are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [output buffering functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). For example:

```
ob_start();

include('some_page.php');
doSomeOtherStuff();

$contents = ob_get_clean();
```

`$contents` will now contain the contents of the page without actually outputting anything to the browser. You can then echo the contents where you see fit.